# Riverpod prevent multiple refresh - State Notifier Provider

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, state-management, riverpod

The screen is refreshes twice when I use this state notifier provider, how can I prevent it?   I want to load the api data once and only refresh if firestore document is updated.

```
final profileAsyncController =
    StateNotifierProvider<ProfileAsyncNotifier, AsyncValue<ProfileUser?>>(
        (ref) => ProfileAsyncNotifier(ref));
```

```
class ProfileAsyncNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<ProfileUser?>> {
  ProfileAsyncNotifier(this.ref) : super(AsyncLoading()) {
    _init();
  }

  final Ref ref;

  void _init() async {
    var profile = await ref.read(apiServiceProvider)!.getProfile();
   // if (!mounted) return;
    state = AsyncData(profile);

   final firestoreUser = ref.watch(firestoreUserChangeProvider);
    final firestoreDb = ref.read(firestoreDatabaseProvider);
    firestoreUser.whenData((value) {
      if (value!.syncRequired!) {
        firestoreDb!.stopSync();
      }
    });
  }

  void updateProfile(ProfileUser? profile) async {
    state = AsyncLoading();
   state = AsyncData(profile);
  }
}
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
        var profile = ref.watch(profileAsyncController);
        return profile.when(
          loading: () => Container(child: Scaffold(body: Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator()))),
          error: (err, stack) => Text('Error $err'),
          data: (profile) => profileWidget(user: profile),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```